# given a Diophantine equation $ax+by=k$ for which $k$ values ​have a solution

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

given a Diophantine equation $ax+by=k$ and $a,b$ are natural numbers and there $gcd(a,b)=3$ .

for which $k$ values ​​have a solution?

i try do some examples like $3x+3y=2$ and we see that there is no solution.

and for $6x+15y=36$ i found by using euclid algorithm:

$36=5(36-2t)+2(-72+5t)$ and $14<t<18$

but i do not recognize any particular pattern.

I'm sure there is a simple solution that I did not get on it with intuition.

I'd love to see a way to solve problems in this style and a short explanation.

thanks you guys.

Comment: This is a *Diophantine* equation not a "diofant" equation. Try some more examples. If you know $a$ and $b$ are both multiples of $3$ what does this tell you about $k$ ?

Comment: $gcd(a,b)=3$ so $3|a$ and $3|b$ so $3|ax+by$ then $3|k$ then$k=3*c$ ?

Comment: @arthurProject correct. Now let $d=\gcd(a,b)$, so that $d\mid a,b,k$. Write $a=a'd$, $b=b'd$ and $k=k'd$ such that the equation becomes $a'x+b'y=k'$ with $\gcd(a',b')=1$. This only leaves the case $\gcd(a,b)=1$ to consider.